# LoaderInfo parameters in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var myStr:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.benny;
//this code will recieve single value from flashVars.
```

I want to know how to use LoaderInfo.parameters for handle more number of data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loader variables are captured by flash either by get variables inside the URL or by flashvars. You've got it exactly right, its key/value pairs. So basically if you had a URL like this:

```
http://somewhere.com/movie.swf?test1=10&test2=20&benny=benny
```

Inside flash you access these just like you've already been doing:

```
var numberString:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.test1 as String;
var number:Number = root.loaderInfo.parameters.test2 as Number;
var uName:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.benny as String;
```

If you were to trace out the above values, it will show:

```
trace(numberString); //10
trace(number); //20
trace(uName); //benny
```

Heres a link that describes doing the same thing using flashvars:

http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html

Note I use the statement "as String" or "as Number" because by default the values are properties of an Object called "parameters." Doing what I'm doing above explicitly casts these values as the desired type, which is prudent for both optimal VM performance and just plain good coding practice.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm gonna edit to be part of the answer since it may be missed by readers as just a comment.

Comment: Make it easier on yourself and store your parameters into a variable. var flashvars:Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;

Comment: I asked for multiple number of values.

Comment: And I explained that. But whatever. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to know how to load multiple flashVars and read them in your application?

In that case, take a look [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this way :

```
var o : Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;

var flashvars : Array = ['benny','test','etc'];


for(var fv : String in flashvars){
  trace(o[fv]);
}
```